# JS: Add path to DOM element in string format returns a non-desired string as output

Tags: javascript, html, css

In JavaScript, suppose I have a `DOM` element in a variable like this:

```
var first_part = document.querySelectorAll('.sizes.row > .selectric-wrapper > .selectric-items > .selectric-scroll > ul > li')
```

This returns an array with several list items.

Now I'd like to query somewhat deeper, but in my code, it depends which 'route' to take.

In some cases (name it 'scenario 1') I need this path:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.sizes.row > .selectric-wrapper > .selectric-items > .selectric-scroll > ul > li')[0].className
```

In other cases (name it 'scenario 2') I need this path:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.sizes.row > .selectric-wrapper > .selectric-items > .selectric-scroll > ul > li')[0].children[0].title
```

So what I tried was:

```
var second_part = ['[0].className','[0].children[0].title']
```

And then refer to for example scenario 1 like this:

```
var scenario_1 = first_part + second_part[0]
```

The result is this

```
"[object NodeList][0].className"
```

This is not what is required; I'd like to get the value of the `className`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: quick note, instead of `querySelectorAll(...)[0]` it's better to just use `querySelector(...)`

Comment: You can chain querySelectors. Perhaps that might help you? `document.querySelectorAll('.array')[0].querySelector('div a')`

Comment: How come you can't query off of the `querySeletorAll` result directly? Ie what's wrong with `first_part[0].className` and `first_part[0].children[0].title`?

Comment: You're concatenating a `NodeList` and a string. Instead, store the selector as a string, and pass it to `querySelectorAll`. E.g., `var selector = '.sizes.row > .selectric-wrapper > .selectric-items > .selectric-scroll > ul > li'; var first_part = document.querySelectorAll(selector);` Then you can do `var scenario_1 = selector + second_part[0];` That still won't get you anything actionable, because that's not how JavaScript works. Go with what @QuangdaoNguyen mentions.

Comment: @JannesCarpentier, actually this code is in a loop, so I have to check each list item, therefore the ...All().

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen, the value of first_part actually is different each time because it's part of a loop. And because first_part is different in each loop, second_part (so the path) can also be different, hence the reason of my question, where I used code which is simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is here is because of how the javascript engine interprets the + sign between objects, what does it do in this case is simply calling `toString` method on the two objects and then concatenating the two strings together which is obviously not what you want.

You could do what you want like this in multiple different ways, one way is to save the selector string in a variable to make things shorter

```
const query = '.sizes.row > .selectric-wrapper > .selectric-items > .selectric-scroll > ul > li'
const scenario1 = document.querySelectorAll(query)[0].className
const scenario2 = document.querySelectorAll(query)[0].children[0].title
// dont forget to guard against null values
```

You could also nest query selector queries using the querySelector method it self. you could also take a look at [lodash get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) method, which can do what you want

Comment: thanks, I'll go with this solution. The reason why in my example first_part is stored in a variable including the querySelectorAll is because first_part was actually used in a loop where the DOM element is different each time. Also, in the loop itself, there were already different if-conditions specified for the first_part DOM list elements, hence I thought it would be efficient to just store the document.querySelectorAll(..) in a variable and code further on this directly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is if the targeted element is one there is no need of calling `querySelectorAll` just use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) the following is an example

```
element = document.querySelector('.sizes.row > .selectric-wrapper > .selectric-items > .selectric-scroll > ul > li')
title = element.children[0].title
class_name = element.className
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm actually looking for a more dynamic solution. The value of first_part actually is different each time because it's part of a loop. And because first_part is different in each loop (and storing first_part in a variable), second_part (so the path) can also be different, hence the reason of my question, where I used code which is simplified.